# A simple dimension of a subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I am given a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ and a subspace $S$ of dimension $w$. 
Is it possible to find the dimension of $S^{\perp}$ without actually finding $S^{\perp}$? I mean is there any formula ?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional setting certainly yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $S$ is a subspace of $V$ then $V=S\oplus S^{\perp}$, hence $\dim S^{\perp}=\dim V-\dim S$.